# Drag a Kinetic.Image when edit other Kinetic.Image

Tags: javascript, image, kineticjs, drag

I have 2 Kinetic.Image (A and B) in my canvas.
I want that when I try move A, only the Kinetic.Image B change, and the A doesn't change it position.

My code is:

```
A.on('dragmove',function(event) {
    var x = B.getX();
    var y = B.getY();
    .
    .
    .
});
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about this:

```
image1.on('dragstart', function() {
  this.stopDrag();
  image2.startDrag();
});
```

http://jsbin.com/qamexu/1/edit

I think you can try to use `dragBoundFunc` property here.